# Getting a SIGSEGV error. Cant find the pointer responsible

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I just started studying linked lists in C and I seem to be getting an infinite loop in the print part, tried fixing all loose ends still stuck with the same problem. I've tried debugging multiple times and it's always a SIGSEGV Error. I have used DEV C++ and GCC 4.9.2.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}node;

void print();
node *clist(int n);
node *head = NULL;

int main() 
{
    int n;
    printf("Input the number of nodes for the Linked List.\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    clist(n);
    print();

    return 0;
}

void print() 
{
    node *show = NULL;
    show = head;
    while (show != NULL) {
        printf("%d => ", show->data);  
        show = (show->next);
    }

    printf("NULL");

}

node *clist(int n) 
{
    node *temp = NULL;
    node *p = NULL;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

        printf("Enter the element %d of the list", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &temp->data);

        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = temp;

        }

        else { 
      p = head; 
      while( p->next ) 
           { 
              p = p->next; 
            } 
            p->next = temp; //UPDATE: SIGSSEGV ERROR HERE NOW 
            }
              }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by your clist method, and how it actually creates a linked list of size n. Have you tried using a debugger (i.e. gdb) to pinpoint exactly where the SIGSEGV is coming from?

Comment: Glancing at this you have two `continue` statements meaning `p->next = temp` is never executed.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding:  1) please consistently indent the code: indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) use meaningful variable (and parameter) names.  names like: 1p1 and `n` are meaningless, even in the current context.  3) Separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line,  4) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)

Comment: OT: regarding: `temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc  2) when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: OT: regarding: `{   p = head;`  please follow the axiom:  *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: You've changed the code from before. As it stands, it's crashing because you're dereferencing a null pointer (you're trying to use p->next = temp when p is null). Make sure the code you show is exactly what you're running.

Comment: OT:  regarding: `scanf("%d",&temp->data);`  When calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (which is the number of successful input format conversions) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: strongly suggest removing both of the `continue` statements.

Comment: regarding: `else
  {   p = head;

   p = p->next;

   continue;
  }
  p->next = temp;`  This does not append a node to the linked list.  Suggest:  `else
  {  
   p = head;

            while( p->next )
            {
       p = p->next;
   }
      p->next = temp;
  }`

Comment: regarding: `void  print();`   when writing a prototype for a function that takes no parameters, always insert `void` between the parens.

Comment: OT: regarding: `node *show = NULL;
 show = head;`  This can be easily reduced to: `node *show = head;`

Comment: regarding: `printf("NULL");`  This is a very poor idea.  Suggest: `printf( "\n" );`  or even better: `puts( "" );`  or `putc( '\n' );`

Comment: OT: regarding the statement in `main()`  `clist(n);` and the function: `node *clist( int n )`   Since the returned value from `clist()` is being ignored, the return type can be `void` and the statement: `return head;` can be removed

Comment: OT: regarding: `while(show!=NULL)` This can be simplified to `while( show )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. properly checks for and handles errors
4. is consistently indented
5. cleans up after itself
6. avoids redundancy in statements like: `if( head == NULL )`
7. eliminates unused returned values
8. properly declares function prototypes that take no parameters
9. for ease of readability, uses appropriate horizontal spacing

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct snode
{
    int data;
    struct snode *next;
} node;

// prototypes
void  print( void );
void  clist( int n );
void  cleanup( void );

node *head = NULL;


int main( void )
{
    int n;

    printf( "Input the number of nodes for the Linked List.\n" );
    if( scanf( "%d", &n ) != 1 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf for number of data points failed\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    clist( n );
    print();
    cleanup();
    return 0; // << optional in modern C
}


void print()
{   
    node *show = head;

    while( show )
    {
        printf( "%d => ", show->data );
        show = show->next;
    }

    puts( "" );
}


void clist( int n )
{
    node *temp = NULL;
    node *p = NULL;

    for( int i=0; i<n; i++ )
    {
        temp = malloc( sizeof( node ) );
        if( !temp )
        {
            perror( "malloc failed" );
            cleanup();
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // EDIT:
        temp->next = NULL;
        // end EDIT:

        printf( "Enter the element %d of the list", i+1 );
        if( scanf( "%d", &temp->data ) != 1 )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "scanf for a data failed\n" );
            cleanup();
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        if( !head )
        {  // list empty
            head = temp;
        }

        else
        {  // list already contains some nodes
            p = head;

            while( p->next )
            {
                p = p->next;
            }
            p->next = temp;
        }
    }
}


void cleanup()
{
    node *temp = head;
    node *current;

    while( temp )
    {
        current = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
        free( current );
    }
}
```

here is the output from a simple run of the program:

```
Input the number of nodes for the Linked List.
2
Enter the element 1 of the list1
Enter the element 2 of the list2
1 => 2 =>
```

Suggest putting a space before the user input for the node data value in the output

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code and added explanatory comments in line:

```
node *clist(int n)
{
    node *temp = NULL;
    node *p = NULL;
    node *prePtr=NULL; //define this to keep track of previous node
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

        printf("Enter the element %d of the list", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &temp->data);
        //temp->next=NULL;
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = temp;
            head->next=NULL; //Make head OR above Temp next pointer NULL
        }

        else {
      p = head;
      //while( p->next ) This is not condition
        while( p!=NULL )//Check for a condition that became false eventually.
        {
               prePtr=p;//to keep track of the previous location
                        //because you cannot add another node if you are 
                        //already ahead of that node.
              p = p->next;//this make you ahead of the node where you want
                         //to insert node when wile condition became false.
            //}
        }
            //p->next = temp; //UPDATE: SIGSSEGV ERROR HERE NOW
            //above line try to add a node on next while it's already NULL.
                prePtr->next=temp;//this take previous node and add a temp to its next node
                temp->next=p;//here you assign temp->next=p which is NULL
            }
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: regarding: *//while( p->next ) This is not condition*   Actually, this is a 'condition'  if 'next' contains NULL, then the `while()` loop will exit.  Otherwise the `while()` loop will iterate again

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: Please read the comment, to the OPs question, about casting the returned value from `malloc()`